# difference between new android application project and new android sample project on eclipse

Tags: android

I am newbie to the world of Android. Just wanted to know what is the difference between a new android application project and new android sample project on eclipse. When I click on new android sample project, it directly shows me the Android API level display. The display says "This target has no samples" and that is true if I pick any API level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New android sample project allows you to access the sample projects provided by the SDK which you need to download from the android manager. So on Eclipse go to->Android SDK manager ->once you open the package details you can find **Samples for SDK** (each API level have samples, you may get for the latest target which would be backward compatible up to certain API level). Install the ones you need. Then you will find samples for the target under new android sample project.

New android project is for starting new project without using the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Android Sample Projects give you demo projects that demonstrate an android functionality (e.g., Accelerometer, ApiDemos, ContactManager, etc) which you can run and check the code on how it works.

By the looks of it, you haven't installed your Android Samples. Check the Android SDK Manager and check "Samples for SDK".